# How to interrupt a function call in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to use a Third Party Internal Library which is processing a given request. Unfortunately it is synchronous in nature. Also I have no control on the code for the same. Basically it is a function call. This function seems to a bit erratic in behavior. Sometimes this function takes 10 ms to complete processing and sometimes it takes up to 300 secs to process the request.

Can you suggest me a way to write a wrapper around this function so that it would throw an interrupted exception if the function does not complete processing with x ms/secs. I can live with not having the results and continue processing, but cannot tolerate a 3 min delay.

PS: This function internally sends an update to another system using JMS and waits for that system to respond and sends apart from some other calculations.

Comment: call the method using a thread and kill the thread after x amount of time?

Comment: he said it's synchronous... won't be that easy... you need to modify the code of library itself if it doesn't support timeouts imo.

Comment: Look at Executors interface, launch your function in separate thread and use some time limiting method like awaittermination. More on this here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Comment: Couldn't you still throw it in a thread then start a timer that either kills the thread after a certain time or gets stopped on response from the call if it beats the timer?

Answer (score 4):

> Can you suggest me a way to write a wrapper around this function so that it would throw an interrupted exception if the function does not complete processing with x ms/secs.

This is not possible.  `InterruptException` only gets thrown by specific methods.  You can certainly call `thread.stop()` but this is deprecated and not recommended for a number of reasons.

A better alternative would be for your code to wait for the response for a certain amount of time and just abandon the call if doesn't work.  For example, you could submit a `Callable` to a thread pool that actually makes the call to the "Third Party Internal Library".  Then your main code would do a `future.get(...)` with a specific timeout.

```
// allows 5 JMS calls concurrently, change as necessary or used newCachedThreadPool()
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
...
// submit the call to be made in the background by thread-pool
Future<Response> future = threadPool.submit(new Callable<Response>() {
   public Response call() {
      // this damn call can take 3 to 3000ms to complete dammit
      return thirdPartyInternalLibrary.makeJmsRequest();
   }
});
// wait for some max amount of time
Response response = null;
try {
    response = future.get(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 100);
} catch (TimeoutException te) {
    // log that it timed out and continue or throw an exception
}
```

The problem with this method is that you might spawn a whole bunch of threads waiting for the library to respond to the remote JMS query that you would not have a lot of control over.

No easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

This will throw a `TimeoutException` if the lambda doesn't finish in the time allotted:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> yourCall()).get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tried this and this does seem to work. Unfortunately we are currently using Java 1.7 and hence may not be able to fully utilize these features. Thanks for the answer though. Another Reason to push for Java 1.8 for our app.

Comment: Also I cannot Vote Up because I am new to StackOverflow and don't have the privileges to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Being that this is 3rd party you cannot modify the code. As such you will need to do two things

1. Launch the execution in a new thread.
2. Wait for execution in current thread, with timeout.

One possible way would be to use a Semaphore.

```
    final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do work
            semaphore.release();
        }
    });

    t.start();
    try {
        semaphore.tryAcquire(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // Whatever your timeout is
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // handle cleanup
    }
```

The above method is gross, I would suggest instead updateing your desing to use a dedicated worker queue or RxJava with a timeout if possible.